# how to make email existence check faster?

Tags: python, django, multithreading, email-validation

I am using [email validator](https://github.com/syrusakbary/validate_email) to validate if a email address exists or not. The process seems very time consuming. I have tried using [interruptingcow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/interruptingcow/) to decrease the time taken by each email address waiting for Timeout response. This method worked outside django but inside django, I couldn't call interruptingcow as it asks to be called from the main thread and I have tried many ways to solve it, but failed.

Secondly, I tried multi threading the process, the thread runs just the way i wanted to but I can't get a return value from the thread. For which I tried implementing a Queue, which wasn't of quite the help.

I would like to ask for any supplements of the validate_email or want the process called by

```
validate_email("emailaddress@email.com",verify=True)
```

to run faster as I would have to process about 20 emails at a time.

Any suggestions or help is most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I usually relegate external processes to celery, it is an industry standard for such things

http://www.celeryproject.org/

If i need to run one background task for a project, django-tasks is usually sufficient for longer processing tasks, is easier to setup and doesn't need external queueing like rabbitmq or redis, which celery needs

https://code.google.com/p/django-tasks/

Comment: I actually want to check and display the email validity in real time, not as a background activity

Comment: yeah, but since it is a tedious process, you don't need to do it during the course of a single request/response.

program your worker code to give you back feedback (starting/processing/result) which you will display on the front, both celery and django-task can do this